# java unit test ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing

I'm having trouble finding a way to unit test some code that uses multiple threads.  Below is the code that is giving me problems:

```
public class ThreadHandler {
  private ExecutorService executorService;
  private boolean isFinished = false;

  public void start() {
    isFinished = false;
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
  }

  public void stop() {
    isFinished = true;
    executorService.shutdown();
  }

  public void listen(final ServerSocket serverSocket) throws IOException {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
          while (!isFinished) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            executorService.submit(new ClassIWantToMockOut(socket));
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          ...
        } finally {
          try {
            socket.close();
          } catch(IOException e) {
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    };

    this.createThread(runnable);
  }

  public void createThread(Runnable runnable) {
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(runnable);
    serverThread.start();
  }
}
```

I would like to test the **listen** method by mocking out ClassIWantToMockOut(socket).  As far as I've read, though, it is not possible to mock a class constructor.  Is there anything I could do to make this code more unit test friendly?

Comment: "Below is the code that is giving me problems:" , what problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what *factories* are for.  Define a factory that creates new instances of `ClassIWantToMockOut`.

```
public class CIWTMOFactory {
    ClassIWantToMockOut newInstance(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        return new ClassIWantToMockOut(serverSocket);
    }
}
```

Then give your `ThreadHandler` class two constructors.  One accepts a factory object as an argument, the other uses a default factory.

```
class ThreadHandler {
    private static final CIWTMOFactory defaultFactory = new CIWTMOFactory();
    private final CIWTMOFactory ciwtmoFactory;

    public ThreadHandler() {
        ciwtmoFactory = defaultFactory;
        ...
    }

    public ThreadHandler(CIWTMOFactory ciwtmoFactory) {
        this.ciwtmoFactory = ciwtmoFactory;
        ...
    }

    public void listen(...) throws ... {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ...
                executorService.submit(ciwtmoFactory.newInstance(socket));
                ...
            };
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Now your unit tests can pass in a factory that returns the mock `ClassIWantToMockOut` object.

---

The *factory* pattern is a special case of a more general pattern for which I do not know the name.  The problem is, you want to unit test class `C` that calls a bunch of `static` methods from package `P`.  The solution is, you define a new class, `PAdapter` with however many *instance* methods, and each instance method does nothing but call a static method from package P with the same name and args.

After you re-write class `C` to make all of its "static" method calls by going through an instance of `PAdapter`, you will then be able to write unit tests for `C` that pass in a mock/stub/fake/whatever `PAdapter` instance.